# How to make an On/off 'signal lamp' using DataInputStream?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, network-programming

I'd like to make a program that can send signal through a network using DataInputStream but I have a trouble with the algorithm.

The program is simple actually. All I need is making two GUIs. The one is a color button (red, yellow, and blue button), another one is only three shapes that changes the color when we click the button.

So here is the client (signal buttons) code

```
connect.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try{
                String str = tf.getText();
                s = new Socket(str,54321);
                out = s.getOutputStream();
                dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
                System.out.println("connection succeeded");
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("connection error");
            }
        }
    });
    JButton disconnect = new JButton ("切断");
    disconnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            try{
                dos.close();
                out.close();
                s.close();
                System.out.println("connection closed");
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println("error -" +ex.toString());
            }
        }   
    });
```

And here is the server (signal lamps). This is the problem.
Sorry if my code is not so efficient.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class lamp extends JFrame{
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    Socket s = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    String iro;
    int s1,s2,s3;
    private Container contentPane;
    public lamp(String title){
        super(title);
            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        setSize(670,300);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawOval(10,50,200,200);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.drawOval(220,50,200,200);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawOval(430,50,200,200);
        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(54321);
            s = ss.accept();
            in = s.getInputStream();
            dis = new DataInputStream(in);
            iro = dis.readUTF();
            s1 = 0;
            s2 = 0;
            s3 = 0;
            if(iro=="1"){
                if(s1==0){
                    s1=1;
                    g.setColor(Color.blue);
                    g.fillOval(10,50,200,200);
                    System.out.println("received blue");
                }else{
                    s1=0;
                    g.setColor(Color.blue);
                    g.fillOval(10,50,200,200);
                    System.out.println("received blue");
                }       
            }
            //its the same statement for yellow and red
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error");
        }
     }
    public static void main(String []args){
        new lamp("lamp");
    }
}
```

The result

```
error
error
error
error
error
```

Any idea?

Comment: [How to compare Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Generally speaking, your approach is wrong, have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` to your `catch` block where you print error to get more details about the cause

Comment: to see what is the error please change System.out.println("error"); with 
e.printStackTrace(); then post the result again

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the advice. I already used     `System.err.println(to.String());` and the result was "address already in use". Can you teach me how to 'close' the address while switching to other colors?

Comment: Don't create the `ServerSocket` in the paint method. See my second comment as to why